# Powershell One Liner with spaces from CMD

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have to create a Powershell Oneliner which will be called from CMD.

The Powershell should uninstall an .MSI first and then install another one.

The Problem is the .MSI I have to install has spaces in its name.
The first part of the command works, but obviously the second part doesn't work.
How could I solve it?

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -command "Start-process msiexec.exe -wait -Argumentlist '/x {aaaaaaaaaaaa} /qn';Start-Process msiexec.exe -wait -ArgumentList '/i `"the msi with spaces in it.msi`" ADV_SUPRESSDATABASETEST=1 SERVER_PROP='someserver\AB' DATABASE_PROP='DATABASE' SQL_TRUSTED_CONNECTION=1'"
```

I have also tried with $variables, but with single quote they aren't expanded. (it's possible to use variables in a one-liner?

How could I possibly solve this?

Comment: _Why_ would you need to call `msiexec` from CMD via Powershell? Either go with all-CMD or, preferably, all-Powershell. There is little if any need to mix psh and batch scripts.

Comment: Because I have to make a repair string for a SCCM Application.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside that calling `msiexec.exe` with `start /wait` directly from `cmd.exe` (a batch file) may be the better solution, as discussed in the comments on the question, you can make this work via the Windows PowerShell CLI (`powershell.exe`) as follows:

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -command Start-process msiexec.exe -wait -Argumentlist '/x {aaaaaaaaaaaa} /qn'; Start-Process msiexec.exe -wait -ArgumentList '/i "the msi with spaces in it.msi" ADV_SUPRESSDATABASETEST=1 SERVER_PROP="someserver\AB" DATABASE_PROP="DATABASE" SQL_TRUSTED_CONNECTION=1'
```

- The outer `"..."` around the `-command` argument have been removed to avoid nested double quotes.

  - In case where you do need nested `"`-quoting, use `\"`<sup>[1]</sup> with the *Windows PowerShell* CLI (`powershell.exe`) and - more robustly `""` with the  *PowerShell [Core] 7+* CLI (`pwsh.exe`).
  - Note: If the command for PowerShell contained unquoted characters such as `&` and `|`, they would be interpreted by *`cmd.exe`*, which can be avoided by enclosing the entire command in `"..."` or by *individually* `^`-escaping such characters (e.g., `^&` to pass `&` through to PowerShell).
- What is inside the `'...'` strings is directly passed to `msiexec` and must therefore use `"`-quoting only.

---

<sup>[1] Even though PowerShell-*internally* it is `` ` `` that serves as the escape character.</sup>